# Filter in array inside another

Tags: javascript

I have this array that I call parent array

I should search name inside nested data array and I expect the same array filtered:

I'm using this code but it is not returning the entire parent array, but just the object inside data.

how can return the entire parent array filtered?

```js
const result = [{
      key: 'A',
      title: 'titleA',
      data: [{
          name: 'name1',
          id: 'id',
        },
        {
          name: 'name2',
          id: 'id',
        }
      ]
    },

    {
      key: 'B',
      title: 'titleB',
      data: [{
          name: 'name3',
          id: 'id',
        },
        {
          name: 'name4',
          id: 'id',
        }
      ]
    },

  ]

  const data = 'name4';
const doSearch = result.reduce((prev, next) => prev.concat(next.data), [])
  .filter(item => item.name == data);

console.log(doSearch)
```

Comment: I tried to make a [mcve] but the code gives errors

Comment: You mean, you want to filter items from the original array without losing its original structure?

Comment: What should the end result look like?

Comment: just use filter inside map. like @epascarello mentioned, please provide sample output.

Comment: @FZs yes, now i have only the object inside data, but not the entire structure

Comment: Can you share the expected output for a given input?

Comment: @HassanImam expected output:
[{
        key: 'B',
        title: 'titleB',
        data: [
            {
                name: 'test',
                id: '3',
            },
            {
                name: 'name',
                id: '4',
            },
        ],
    },]

Answer (score 1):

```
const result = [
    {
        key: 'A',
        title: 'titleA',
        data: [
            {
                name: 'name',
                id: '1',
            },
            {
                name: 'test',
                id: '2',
            },
        ],
    },

    {
        key: 'B',
        title: 'titleB',
        data: [
            {
                name: 'test',
                id: '3',
            },
            {
                name: 'name',
                id: '4',
            },
        ],
    },
];

const filteredNames = (search) => {
    return result.map((obj) => {
        return {
            ...obj,
            data: obj.data.filter(({ name, id }) => name === search),
        };
    });
};

console.log(filteredNames('test'));
```

Answer (score 1):

What the provided code is doing is first flattening.
You're probably looking for [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
const filteredResults = result.filter(({ data }) => (
  data.some(({ name }) => name === data)
));
```

```js
const result = [
  {
    key: 'A',
    title: 'titleA',
    data: [
      {
        name: 'name1',
        id: 'id',
      },
      {
        name: 'name2',
        id: 'id',
      },
    ],
  },

  {
    key: 'B',
    title: 'titleB',
    data: [
      {
        name: 'name 3',
        id: 'id',
      },
      {
        name: 'name 4',
        id: 'id',
      },
    ],
  },
];

const filteredResults = result.filter(entry => (
  entry.data.some(item => item.name === 'name1')
));

document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(filteredResults, null, 2)
```

```html
<pre id="target"></pre>
```

Comment: why return name2 if passed name1?

Comment: Since this is filtering only the results array for any entry which has data[index].name matching the string value.
Were you expecting a list with only the data entries?

Comment: result.filter(entry =>
        entry.data.some(item =>
          item.name
            .toString()
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(data.toString().toLowerCase().trim()),
        ),
      );

Comment: return only match word

Comment: exclude result that not contains the word

Answer (score 0):

```
 const doSearch = result.filter(entry =>
    entry.data.some(item =>
      item.name
        .toString()
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(data.toString().toLowerCase().trim()),
    ),
  );
```